# How do I update a tensor in Pytorch after indexing twice?

Tags: python, pytorch

I know how to update a tensor after indexing into part of it like this:

```py
import torch

b = torch.tensor([0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=torch.uint8)
b[b] = 2
b
# tensor([0, 2, 0, 2], dtype=torch.uint8)
```

but is there a way I can update the *original* tensor after indexing into it twice? E.g.

```py
i = 1
b = torch.tensor([0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=torch.uint8)
b[b][i] = 2
b
# tensor([0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=torch.uint8)
```

What I'd like is for `b` to be `tensor([0, 1, 0, 2])` at the end. Is there a way to do this?

I know that I can do

```py
masked = b[b]
masked[i] = 2
b[b] = masked
b
# tensor([0, 1, 0, 2], dtype=torch.uint8)
```

but is there any better way? It seems that this must be inefficient; if `masked` is very large, I'm updating many locations in `b` when I've really only changed one.

(In case a different approach than indexing twice would work better, the general problem I have is how to change the value in an original tensor at the `i`th location of a masked version of that tensor.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adopted another solution from [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/find-indices-with-value-zeros/10151), and compared it to your solution:

Solution:

```
b[b.nonzero()[i]] = 2
```

Runtime comparison:

```
import torch as t
import numpy as np
import timeit


if __name__ == "__main__":

    np.random.seed(12345)
    b = t.tensor(np.random.randint(0,2, [1000]), dtype=t.uint8)
    # inconvenient way to think of a random index halfway that is 1.
    halfway = np.array(list(range(len(b))))[b == 1][len(b[b == 1]) //2]

    runs = 100000

    elapsed1 = timeit.timeit("mask=b[b]; mask[halfway] = 2; b[b] = mask", 
                             "from __main__ import b, halfway", number=runs)

    print("Time taken (original): {:.6f} ms per call".format(elapsed1 / runs))

    elapsed2 = timeit.timeit("b[b.nonzero()[halfway]]=2",
                             "from __main__ import b, halfway", number=runs)

    print("Time taken (improved): {:.6f} ms per call".format(elapsed2 / runs))
```

Results:

```
Time taken (original): 0.000096 ms per call
Time taken (improved): 0.000047 ms per call
```

Results for vector of length `100000`

```
Time taken: 0.010284 ms per call
Time taken: 0.003667 ms per call
```

So the solutions differ only by factor 2. I'm not sure if this is the optimal solution, but depending on your size (and how often you call the function) it should give you a rough idea of what you're looking at.

Comment: I do like this better. In my own tests (indexing into a tensor of shape 100_000 x 100 around halfway through the masked portion), I found your method to be 10x as fast as mine (4 ms vs 40 ms). Either method is still quite fast even at this size, but I found yours reads at least as well and only takes one line. The memory usage should be less as well, which could make a difference with large tensors especially on GPUs, though I haven't tested that.

Comment: Good point, I haven't looked into whether your method does in fact copy the tensor, even though it would only have the size of all non-zero entries (so negligible for sparse matrices). Glad to have found an improvement on your solution anyways :)

Comment: I think the tensor must be copied, at least once I modify the masked version, because otherwise the masked and original tensors would both be modified and I wouldn't have had this issue. So if my mask selects most of the rows of the original tensor, I would need twice the memory to store the original + masked tensors. (in my application, the mask initially selects all rows and then in later calls selects fewer and fewer, so the double-memory case would apply at least initially). I suppose PyTorch could only copy the part of the tensor that's modified, but that seems too tricky.